# Android (Java) - Crash by Camera.Open();

Tags: java, android

Sry for my bad english im from germany.
After the Splash Screen crash my app. (camera app).
what is wrong?

Manifest

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Line
LogCar Error in the Line

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + savePath + "/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));    
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    //Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Preview.this.invalidate();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As explained,

> **Camera android.hardware.Camera.open()**
>
> public static Camera open ()
>
> Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on
>   the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this
>   returns null.

*Does your device has back-facing camera ?*

Comment: @user3803645 - then mention which exception are you getting ?

Comment: i have tested the normal camera app and it is to crash 0.o

Comment: You are getting crash then either put the logcat that mentions the crash report OR which exception are you getting just tell.